# Reloading NSTableView on re-focus

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview

In my application, I have a `NSWindow` that has a `NSTableView` object and a few buttons. When the user presses the "new" button, an "ItemAdd" `NSWindowController` is activated where the user types in attributes for the item to be added to the `NSTableView`.

My question is this: since `NSTableView` requires `reloadData`to update its view, how do I call `reloadData` after the ItemAdd window closes and focus shifts back to the NSWindow with the `NSTableView`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put reload data in a notification handler:

Put this in an initialization method of an object that you want the notification to get called on:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didBecomeMainWindow) name:@"NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification" object:nil];
```

Then make a method something like this:

```
- (void) didBecomeMainWindow
{
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: NSTableView does not have a corresponding NSTableViewController like UITableView does, and thus, no viewDidLoad.

Comment: Sorry, too much iPhone/Mac confusion... ;)

Comment: @Adrian Sarli - Yeah, I totally agree, I do the same thing all the time :)

Comment: @Adrian Sarli: note that your code, as is, is specifying a **C-string** value of `"NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification"`. You should likely remove the quotes from around that to use the `NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` constant defined in `NSWindow.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the NSWindow and override the following method:
***- (void)becomeKeyWindow***